# boxplot with linear fit doesn't use coefficients

Tags: r, regression

I tried a simple boxplot of two categories (transmission type is either 0 or 1) with an added linear fit and expected it to go through the means of the boxplots, but something is wrong here:

```
linearFit <- lm(mpg~am, data=mtcars)
boxplot(mpg~am, data=mtcars) 
abline(linearFit, lwd=2, col="blue")

linearFit$coefficients
# (Intercept)          am 
#   17.147368    7.244939
```

However the line is well beyond the two boxplots instead of going through the intercept for "category" 0. How can I tell R to use the category means in the base plotting system?

EDIT to clarify:
So I just need one blue line, that goes through (0, 17.14) and (1, 17.14+7.244) within this boxplot where the variable 'am' (transmission type) is a factor instead of a numeric variable.
Is there an easy way to do this in the base plotting system?

Comment: thanks for editing, Henrik!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, `am` is treated like a factor, the coefficient for `am` is a shift to the intercept. You thus have to add this to the intercept to get the am=1 intercept.

```
linearFit <- lm(mpg~am, data=mtcars)
boxplot(mpg~am, data=mtcars, border=1:2 )
abline(h=c(linearFit$coefficients[1], linearFit$coefficients[1]+linearFit$coefficients[2]), col=1:2, lty=2, lwd=2)
```

[image]

Also, the significance of the `am` term can be tested by comparison to a model with only the intercept included (i.e. "1")

```
linearFit0 <- lm(mpg~1, data=mtcars) # model with intercept only
anova(linearFit0, linearFit)
```

#### Edit - plotting outside boxplot

```
plot(x=c(0,1), res$stats[3,], ylim=range(res$stats))
segments(x0=c(0,1), x1=c(0,1), y0=res$stats[2,], y1=res$stats[4,])
abline(linearFit)
```

[image]

#### Edit2 - shift values for boxplot

```
linearFit <- lm(mpg~I(am+1), data=mtcars)
boxplot(mpg~I(am+1), data=mtcars, border=1:2 )
abline(linearFit$coefficients, col=1:2, lty=2, lwd=2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. But your code produces two horizontal lines - I need one line going through the means of each category/factor.

Comment: That is what you are getting (or I don't understand your question completely) - each line represents the mean of the am factor levels 0 and 1.

Comment: sorry, I just need one blue line, that goes through (0, 17.14) and (1, 17.14+7.244), but the factors somehow break things here

Comment: I think you are not understanding the result of your model completely if you want to do that - `am` is not a continuous variable, and thus a sloping line is not appropriate.

Comment: hmm, I do understand that the line doesn't make sense between 0 and 1 but it definitely shows a trend, right?

So How do I convert it to a numeric variable first and set the labels on the x axis to be just 0 and 1 then (i.e. I want to fake numeric values if that's what it takes)

Comment: The problem is that the am=0 level is actually being plotted at x=1, and am=1 is at x=2. This get's ugly, but I now show how to extract the boxplot results and plot outside the function.

Comment: hmm, your explanation is interesting, but when I plot `abline(lm(mpg~as.numeric(am+1), data=mtcars), lwd=2, col="blue")` instead then the slope doesn't quite fit

Comment: Don't add +1 to `am`. Only boxplot is treating it like a factor : `plot(mpg~am, data=mtcars); abline(lm(mpg~am, data=mtcars), lwd=2, col="blue")`

Comment: No my point was: If the boxplot just used the wrong x coords for plotting, then a shift of the abline should produce the correct result - but it doesn't, so there is a different transformation going on.

So the question now is: how do I add boxplots to a grapph with numeric x axis? :-)

Comment: Actually you were right with the simple transformation (x shift), I just forgot that we see the medians and not the means in the boxplots, so doing the (am+1) shift and adding this `points(c(lmCoef[1], lmCoef[1]+lmCoef[2]),col="red",pch=19)` we see that the line has the correct slope!

If you add that to your answer then I can accept it - thanks so much for pointing out the transformation!